# Правильно ли сказано и нет ли в данном предложении противоречий?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Давай, выкладывай видосы с другом! Когда он уже будет коры мочить?

Answer (score 2):

Если запись предназначена для известной аудитории, то слова и выражения молодежного жаргона можно не обозначать кавычками, и тогда все верно. Если вы не уверены в том, что всё будет понято, то используются кавычки иди другое выделение:

**Давай, выкладывай *видосы* с другом! Когда он уже будет *коры мочить*?**

Для справок: Выражение "мочить коры" означает дурачиться, веселить людей, совершать что-то экстравагантное или из рядя вон выходящее. Видос (мол. жаргон) – видеоролик.

Слово «давай» выделено запятой **верно**.

**Пояснение**

1. Частица «давай» может находиться в тесной связи со следующим за ней глаголом. В этом случае  она  используется для образования повелительного наклонения и не обособляется.

Из словаря: **ДАВАТЬ,**  <Давай(те), в зн. частицы. (с инф. нсв. или с 1 л. мн. ч. буд. вр.). Разг. 1. Выражает приглашение к совместному действию или побуждение к действию. Д. мириться! Давайте посидим, отдохнём, покурим. Спи д.! Давайте поторапливайтесь. Д. отсюда! (грубо; убирайся). Д. все по домам (расходись, разбегайся). Давай бог ноги (о быстром, поспешном бегстве).

Можно записать: *Давай выкладывай видосы с другом!* Но такая запись **менее выразительная.**

2. Если «давай» используется для уточнения или повторения действия, а после него идёт другой глагол в повелительном наклонении, то между ними может ставиться запятая. В этом случае  **действие выражено два раза** (однородные сказуемые, обозначение паузы): *Давай (действуй),  не ленись! Ещё пять отжиманий и отдохнёшь. Давай,  выкладывай видосы с другом!*

Подробно тему с частицей «давай» можно посмотреть по ссылке
https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/davaj-zapyataya-posle-slova-nuzhna-ili-net

Comment: Второй пункт из Пояснения можно расширить примером с возможным многоточием по месту возможной запятой. Из «Русских женщин» Н. А. Некрасова: "Я всё рассказала доступное вам / По вашим ребяческим летам. / Идите гулять по полям, по лугам! / Идите же... пользуйтесь летом!" Жаль только, что мы никогда не узнаем, на какие противоречия намекал автор вопроса.